# Keep Integer Matrix in R as Integer Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose that I have an integer matrix in R filled with "1".

When I divide it by two it will be converted to a double matrix.

How can I force R to not change the type matrix?
(So the matrix will be filled with 0 instead of .5).

It is true that I can use `round` function later, but it decrease the speed significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer division (%/%) instead of normal division (/):

```
1%/%2 = 0
1/2=0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Euclidian division, `%/%`, and make sure you divide by `2L`, not `2`.

```
x <- matrix(1L, 5, 5)
str( x %/% 2L )
# int [1:5, 1:5] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Dose it return the `floor` of results? I need the `round` of results.

Comment: Yes. In this case you need to do the computations with floating point numbers and actually use `round`.

Comment: Thanks but this method is slower than using `round` it self!

Comment: `round` looks slower to me: 
`N <- 1000;
system.time( replicate(50, matrix(1L,1000,1000) %/% 2L) );
system.time( replicate(50, round(matrix(1L,1000,1000) / 2)) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell it to keep the integer. It has no effect on your runtime execution.

```
system.time(mym<-apply(matrix(1,1000,1000), 1:2, function(x) as.integer(x/2)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.46    0.01    4.48 
system.time(mym<-apply(matrix(1,1000,1000), 1:2, function(x) x/2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.44    0.00    4.46
```

So just use the as.integer expression and you keep it an integer.