# Why can a matrix 'protect' itself and how can I implement real restrictions to custom classes?

Tags: r, oop

I have been trying to get my ahead around validity of objects. I have read [Hadley's advanced programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) and get what he says about aiming at your feet (with a gun):

> R doesn't protect you from yourself: you can easily shoot yourself in the foot, but if you don't aim the gun at your foot and pull the trigger, you won't have a problem.

So this holds for `S3`. Looking for a more rigorous implementation I looked into `S4`.
The man page to `setValidity` brought up the following:

```
setClass("track",
      representation(x="numeric", y = "numeric"))
t1 <- new("track", x=1:10, y=sort(stats::rnorm(10)))
## A valid "track" object has the same number of x, y values
validTrackObject <- function(object) {
if(length(object@x) == length(object@y)) TRUE
else paste("Unequal x,y lengths: ", length(object@x), ", ",
           length(object@y), sep="")
}
## assign the function as the validity method for the class
setValidity("track", validTrackObject)
## t1 should be a valid "track" object
validObject(t1)
## Now we do something bad
t2 <- t1
t2@x <- 1:20
## This should generate an error
## Not run: try(validObject(t2))
```

Bottom line: If I do not add validObject to the initializer or constructor there's little I can do. Also this post from [Martin Morgan and bioconductor's Seth Falcon](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/initalizing-and-checking-validity-of-S4-classes-td830638.html) was interesting, still though I could always `t2@x <- 1:1111`.

I guess there's not much I can do about this? Though the `matrix` class for example makes me wonder if there's an option.

```
a <- matrix(c(1:12),3,4)
cbind(a,"somechar")
# or similarily
a[1,1] <- "b"
```

Obviously all elements of a `matrix` have to be of the same class. So that's why once a character is added all elements are coerced to the common denominator, which is class `character`.

So my question is: How is this possible? In which way is the matrix class defined, that it can protect the restriction "some class for all elements" by any means? And is there a way to implement such a restriction to a custom class, too?

E.g.: class of class 'customlist' that has to be a named list and names being restricted to only be two chars long.

Comment: I asked nearly similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758585/keep-integer-matrix-in-r-as-integer-matrix/18758741?noredirect=1#comment27654092_18758741, but answering this question can solve that problem as well.

Comment: hmm, maybe I don't get it, but the answers seem to be quite different from what I expect here. My question is rather about OOP and how could use the described property of a matrix in a definition of a custom class.

Comment: The coercion is a part of R's language definition, not a part of the matrix "class". You'll get exactly the same behaviour with, eg, `x <- 1:10; x[5] <- "foo"`.

Comment: ok thought so, but is there a way then to implement a custom restriction to let's say a list. e.g. that a list must be named?

Comment: @MattBannert I suspect you'll need to define a new class, say `mattsmatrix` that is almost like a `matrix` but with your specialized restrictions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft exactly that's what I am asking for. I just do not know how to implement it. How can I define a new class that REALLY forces its restrictions to be pushed through. In my question I show how bad stuff can be entered despite validObject and all of those.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to prevent you (or your users) doing silly things with assignment, short of possibly overriding `<-`.  Since that is primitive, and quite fundamental to R, there is a danger of breaking other things if you go down that route.

If you use reference classes then you can include accessors which allow checks before assignments are made.

```
trackFactory <- setRefClass(
  "track",
  fields = list(
    x = "numeric",
    y = "numeric"
  ),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function(x, y)
    {
      assertIsValid(x, y)
      x <<- x
      y <<- y
    },
    assertIsValid = function(x, y)
    {
      if(length(x) != length(y)) 
      {
        stop(
          "Unequal x,y lengths: ", 
          toString(c(length(x), length(y)))
        )
      }
    },
    setX = function(x)
    {
      assertIsValid(x, .self$y)
      x <<- x
    },
    setY = function(y)
    {
      assertIsValid(.self$x, y)
      y <<- y
    }
  )
)

track1 <- trackFactory$new(1:10, runif(10))
track1$setX(1:5)
## Error in assertIsValid(x, .self$y) : Unequal x,y lengths: 5, 10
```

Unfortunately, you can still use direct assignment to skip the checks.

```
track1$x <- 1:7
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with reference classes, but couldn't you define the equivalent of an S3 `$<-.track`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich May be possible, but it isn't documented or obvious.  I've tried adding a custom `\`<-\` = function(x, value) {}` function to the class, but it doesn't appear to be called

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Ditto with `\`<<-\``, `\`$<-\``, `\`$<<-\``, `\`@<-\``, and `\`.->x\``. Ran out of ideas after that.

Comment: Hmm looks like it is simply not meant to be like that in R. Even if it's not spectacular in the sense of a solution that I can follow – I learned it's the way it is. Thanks folks.